# log4j filename with azure web service hostname

Tags: java, logging, log4j, hostname, azure-web-app-service

I have Azure App services in java. I have log4j logging mechanism in place. I need to have log files created as HOSTNAME_servicename.log
When I deploy the code locally in tomcat, it creates the file with required filename but on azure it creates _servicename.log.

Class:

```
package com.mastek.transaction.filter;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ApplicationConfiguration implements ServletContextListener{

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

    String siteName = System.getenv("COMPUTERNAME");
    System.setProperty("COMPUTERNAME",siteName);

/** The Constant logger. */
final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

 logger.info("SITENAME: " + siteName);
}
}
```

log4j.properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, out, file
log4j.logger.com.mastek=DEBUG

# ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.out.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=../../LogFiles/${COMPUTERNAME}_transaction-rs.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I have added listener in web.xml:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.mastek.security.filter.ApplicationConfiguration</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Deployment logs says below:

```
2017-04-04 14:34:28 WARN  i18n:68 - RESTEASY002175: The use of javax.ws.rs.core.Application is deprecated, please use javax.ws.rs.Application as a context-param instead
2017-04-04 14:34:34 INFO  i18n:479 - RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.mastek.security.rest.service.SwaggerConfiguration
2017-04-04 14:34:35 INFO  i18n:505 - RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource com.mastek.security.rest.service.RegistrationRESTImpl from Application class com.mastek.sec2017-04-04 14:34:40 INFO  i18n:479 - RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.mastek.security.rest.service.Swagger2017-04-04 14:34:43 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:513 - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Apr 04 14:34:43 GMT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-04 14:34:45 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:316 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context.xml]
2017-04-04 14:34:50 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:316 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [persistence-config.xml]
2017-04-04 14:34:58 INFO  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:172 - Loading properties file from URL [file:/sdt/configuration/services.properties]
2017-04-04 14:34:58 WARN  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:181 - Could not load properties from URL [file:/sdt/configuration/services.properties]: \sdt\configuration\servi2017-04-04 14:35:02 INFO  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:172 - Loading properties file from URL [file:/sdt/configuration/services.properties]
2017-04-04 14:35:02 WARN  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:181 - Could not load properties from URL [file:/sdt/configuration/services.properties]: \sdt\configuration\services.properties (The system cannot 2017-04-04 14:35:06 INFO  DriverManagerDataSource:133 - Loaded JDBC driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
2017-04-04 14:35:09 INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2017-04-04 14:35:09 INFO  Version:54 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
2017-04-04 14:35:10 INFO  Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-04-04 14:35:10 INFO  Environment:346 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-04-04 14:35:22 INFO  Dialect:145 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
2017-04-04 14:35:48 INFO  TransactionFactoryInitiator:62 - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2017-04-04 14:35:48 INFO  ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-04-04 14:36:07 WARN  HqlSqlWalker:996 - [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 69.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
2017-04-04 14:36:08 WARN  HqlSqlWalker:996 - [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 79.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
2017-04-04 14:36:08 WARN  HqlSqlWalker:996 - [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 81.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
2017-04-04 14:36:08 WARN  HqlSqlWalker:996 - [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 102.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
2017-04-04 14:36:08 WARN  HqlSqlWalker:996 - [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 102.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
2017-04-04 14:36:08 WARN  HqlSqlWalker:996 - [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 108.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
2017-04-04 14:36:08 WARN  HqlSqlWalker:996 - [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 101.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
2017-04-04 14:36:08 WARN  HqlSqlWalker:996 - [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 107.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
2017-04-04 14:36:25 INFO  HibernateTransactionManager:339 - Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@12232e47] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2017-04-04 14:36:26 INFO  ContextLoader:325 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 107328 ms
2017-04-04 14:36:26 INFO  ApplicationConfiguration:25 - SITENAME: RD0003FF731D3E
```

I have logged the sitename which is giving correctly as above log says but after WebApplicationContext: initialization completed.

Comment: It seems that you had resolved your issue, is it? If not, please update your question.

Comment: No. Its not resolved yet

Answer (score 0):

As reference, there is a wiki page [`Azure runtime environment`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment) of Kudu list some environment variables that you can refer to and get their values via Java code `System.getenv("<azure webapp env name>")`. Or you can refer to [`Adding environment variables`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#adding-environment-variables) to add some custom variables into `applicationHost.xdt`, or just add them in the `Application settings` tab of Azure portal.

---

Update: 
You can set the environment variables for each instances of Azure App service, please see below.

[image]

As reference, please see [here](https://buildazure.com/2015/11/30/azure-web-app-application-settings/).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your thought, how can we access 2 different Kudus for 2 instances so that I can add 2 different customized env variable one for each instance.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have tried using App settings too, its still not getting the value in log4j.properties file. I think the logging is getting initialized before java executes System.getenv()